# Filtering nested arrays on multiple properties and multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create flexible table filtering on user-company-roles objects in JS array. User shall be able to provide filtering on multiple object properties, with multiple values, with use of AND (&&) operand when matching.

I would appreciate tip on how to proceed implementing the logic here. Of course I could loop through the array and have multiple nested if-statements, but maybe there are more clean and nice approach on this?

**User-Company-Roles Array**

```
const userArray = [
{
    "id": "peterpan",
    "name": "Peter pan",
    "company": [
        {
            "id": "12345678",
            "name": "Company A",
            "roles": [
                "Role A",
                "Role B",
                "Role C"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "systemRoles": [
        {
            "systemName": "System A",
            "role": "Admin"
        },
        {
            "systemName": "System B",
            "role": "User"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "robinhood",
    "name": "Robin Hood",
    "company": [
        {
            "id": "9876543",
            "name": "Company B",
            "roles": [
                "Role A"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "546372",
            "name": "Company C",
            "roles": [
                "Role A"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "systemRoles": [
        {
            "systemName": "System B",
            "role": "User"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "biggiant",
    "name": "Big Giant",
    "company": [
        {
            "id": "546372",
            "name": "Company C",
            "roles": [
                "Role A"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "systemRoles": [
        {
            "systemName": "System B",
            "role": "User"
        }
    ]
}
];
```

**Filter object**

```
const filter = {
        includeUserIds: [], // filters 'user.id' that matches values in this array
        includeCompanyNames: [], // filters 'user.company.name' that matches values in this array
        includeSystemRoleNames: [], // filters 'user.systemRoles.role' that matches values in this array
        includeCompanyRoles: [], // filters 'user.company.roles' that matches values in this array
        excludeSystemRoleNames: [], // filters 'user.systemRoles.role' that **DOES NOT** match values in this array
        excludeCompanyRoles: [] // filters 'user.company.roles' that **DOES NOT** match values in this array
    }
```

**Matching**
When filtering the array I want the filter to match user-objects as this (pseudo code):

```
filter.includeUserIds && filter.includeCompanyNames 
    && filter.includeSystemRoleNames && filter.includeCompanyRoles 
    && !filter.excludeSystemRoleNames && !filter.excludeCompanyRoles
```

**Example 1**: Filter users by user id:

```
const filter = {
        includeUserIds: ['peterpan', 'robinhood'],
        includeCompanyNames: [],
        includeSystemRoleNames: [], 
        includeCompanyRoles: [], 
        excludeSystemRoleNames: [],
        excludeCompanyRoles: []
    }
```

Would return array with Peter Pan and Robin Hood users

**Example 2**: Filter by company name

```
const filter = {
        includeUserIds: [],
        includeCompanyNames: ['Company C'],
        includeSystemRoleNames: [], 
        includeCompanyRoles: [], 
        excludeSystemRoleNames: [],
        excludeCompanyRoles: []
    }
```

Would return array with Robin Hood and Big Giant users

**Example 3**: Filter by company roles and system roles

```
const filter = {
        includeUserIds: [],
        includeCompanyNames: [],
        includeSystemRoleNames: ['User'], 
        includeCompanyRoles: ['Role A'], 
        excludeSystemRoleNames: ['Admin'],
        excludeCompanyRoles: []
    }
```

Would return array with Robin Hood and Big Giant users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a decision function for each type of the filter and put it into object with same properties as `filter` is. Each function should accept 2 arguments: `item` of type `any` and `filter` of type `string[]`. So it will look like:

```
const deciders = {
    includeUserIds: (item, filter) => { ... },
    includeCompanyNames: (item, filter) => { ... },
    includeSystemRoleNames: (item, filter) => { ... },
    includeCompanyRoles: (item, filter) => { ... },
    excludeSystemRoleNames: (item, filter) => { ... },
    excludeCompanyRoles: (item, filter) => { ... },
};
```

Then filtering is a simple `filter` of original array like:

```
const filtered = userArray.filter(user => {
  let include = true;
  Object.keys(deciders).forEach(type => include &= deciders[type](user, filter[type]));
  return include;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example of logic within one deciders function?

Comment: Basically it is simple `(item, filter) => filter.indexOf(item) !== -1` but may differ e.g. in a case of a `company` where you have actual value deeper in object